# for loop with if condition in new column in r

Tags: r, loops, grouping

I am new to R and I am trying to divide the data, based on time every 5 minutes. For example, I have the data like bellow minutes that starts from 480 to 1200 min and I want every 5 minutes of this to be grouped together and the same name like groups 1,2,3,.... and have that group name in new column.

Please let me know how I can do that easily as I have a big data and is almost impossible to do it manually.

```
time    Dates   minutes
08:03:00    01/04/2014  483
08:00:00    01/04/2014  480
08:00:00    01/04/2014  480
08:00:00    01/04/2014  480
08:00:00    01/04/2014  480
08:00:00    01/04/2014  480
08:02:00    01/04/2014  482
08:03:00    01/04/2014  483
08:02:00    01/04/2014  482
08:06:00    01/04/2014  486
08:11:00    01/04/2014  491
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp3Hj.png)

Comment: An example of your current data and what the desired output is would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to include some sample data with your questions.

Here's something that ought to work. Using `data.table` to group by time and `lubridate::round_date` to round data to the nearest 5 minutes.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# Dummy data
nobv <- 1000 # number of observations
dat <- data.table(value = rnorm(nobv, mean = 56, sd = 6),
                  time = seq.POSIXt(from = Sys.time(), length.out = nobv, by = 60))


> dat[, .(meanval = mean(value)), by= .(round_date(time, unit = '5 min'))]
              round_date  meanval
  1: 2018-08-13 10:55:00 55.32077
  2: 2018-08-13 11:00:00 52.54964
  3: 2018-08-13 11:05:00 58.38496
  4: 2018-08-13 11:10:00 55.25373
  5: 2018-08-13 11:15:00 57.09708
 ---                             
197: 2018-08-14 03:15:00 60.98019
198: 2018-08-14 03:20:00 54.77937
199: 2018-08-14 03:25:00 58.39377
200: 2018-08-14 03:30:00 55.19714
201: 2018-08-14 03:35:00 58.75665
```

You do not need an additional variable - the time stamp (`round_date`) indicates the time period for which the data is presented. The above example is based on a `mean` value for the specified time interval but you can easily do other operations. For example, if you want the sum, you can use `sum(value)` instead of `mean(value)` in the above code. Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thanks Gautam, I added piece of my data set. so I want the minutes to be separated every 5 min to be one group. I cant see that you labelled the ones that are in the same group here. and lets imaging my data size is 199774 and I have 19 rows and I wanna add another row to it for the class name.